# Stack Overflow's Simple Graphics and Icons

Tags: discussion, design

So I've been poking around some of the various sites that are part of Stack Exchange, and I've noticed that many of the icons are rather simple-looking when compared to other Stack Exchange sites. I'm not bugged by it in any way, yet I can't help but wonder what inclined whoever had the ability to choose the style of these icons to choose a style so plain.

Below are several different examples of SO's graphics compared to other sites':

Stack Overflow graphics

[image: SO votes/answers/views bar] [image: SO vote tool/fav. question star] [image: SO tags] [image: SO badges]

Code Review graphics

[image: CR votes/answers/views bar] [image: CR vote tool/fav. question star] [image: CR tags] [image: CR badges]

Science Fiction & Fantasy graphics

[image: SFF votes/answers/views bar] [image: SFF vote tool/fav. question star] [image: SFF tags] [image: SFF badges]

Role-Playing Games graphics

[image: RPG votes/answers/views bar] [image: RPG vote tool/fav.question star] [image: RPG tags] [image: RPG badges]

Comment: I like the theme. Basic, simple, and gets the job done... like programming. It is SO after all, it's not like we are all designers.

Comment: That's a good point. Just keep it plain and simple, just like how programmers want their code to be as simple and efficient as possible.

Comment: The problem with many of the "themed" designs is that they are best understood only after familiarity with the original. And now you're proposing that we do away with the original. Madness.

Comment: You have also got to remember that SOs design still hasn't dramatically changed since it was first launched while the themes of other SE sites are quite different

Comment: @CodyGray I never proposed that we do away with the current design. I was just wondering why this theme turned out to be simpler than the styles on some of the other Stack Exchange sites. I couldn't care less about replacing it.

Comment: Oh, the little things we take for granted.

Comment: I always liked the subtle Gauß distribution that is used for the up/down-arrows in CrossValidated: http://cdn.sstatic.net/stats/img/sprites.png :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Jin is the designer guy](https://stackexchange.com/users/21721/jin), he designs a theme for each site which is applied after it graduates.

He aims to create themes that reflect the subject of the site, which explains the images you've used as examples. Stack Overflow predates his tenure at Stack Exchange (AFAIK), and in any case what theme would suit Stack Overflow? (In other words: other than being 'simple', is the current theme bad/wrong?)

In any case, check Jin's previous answers from the link above to get some insight into how he does things.

Answer (score 5):

I assume it is because Stack Overflow was the first site, so there was no need to make complicated graphics. When other sites came along, they needed more complex graphics to be unique among all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I would think the Sci-fi and RPG icons are more *thematic* than meant to look different just *to*.